# How to redirect to external URL with post parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, http-redirect

When user hits my end point it has to be redirected to an external URL with url encoded form parameters.

### End point

https://example.com

### Form parameters

name:testing,
id: 123456

This is what I tried for now in Express. It gets redirected to the URL but I don't know how to add parameters.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.redirect(302,'https://example.com'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect with parameters as a POT request.

You have 2 options:

1. add parameters to query string:

   Example: https://example.com/?ParameterOne='xxx'
2. use `res.render`, with parameters and use the following through the view engine u use.

   Example: res.render('index', {parameterOne: xxx})